# How to create request in Asp.net core 1 for testing

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core

In my Asp.net core 1 app I have controller with following method:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPost()]
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RequireHttps]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult> Save()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            var pass = Request.Form["password"].ToString();
            var pass1 = Request.Form["password1"].ToString();
            if (!pass.Equals(pass1))
            {
                return View("~/Views/PasswordRecovery.cshtml");
            }                  
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return View("~/Views/Message.cshtml");
        }
    }
    return View("~/Views/Message.cshtml");
}
```

I want to write a test for this method. So I have written this:

```
[Xunit.Fact]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SavePassNotEqualTest()
{
    var controller = new Controllers.PasswordRecoveryController(_mockRepo.Object);
    var dic = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>();
    dic.Add("password", "test");
    dic.Add("password1", "test1");
    var collection = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection(dic);
    controller.Request.Form = collection;  //request is null

    var result = await controller.Save();
    var viewResult = Xunit.Assert.IsType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult>(result);
    Xunit.Assert.Equal("~/Views/Message.cshtml", viewResult.ViewName);
}
```

The problem is that I need to set some test values to Form, Form is in Request, and Request is NULL. I can not find, how can I create some not NULL request and fill it's Form with values.

**EDIT**
Answers helped me to finish up with following solution:

I've created a method that will return a FormCollection:

```
private Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection GetFormCollection()
{
    var dic = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>();
    dic.Add("password", "test");
    dic.Add("password1", "test1");
    return new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection(dic);
}
```

And my test method is:

```
[Xunit.Fact]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SavePassNotEqualTest()
{           
    var controller = new Findufix.Controllers.PasswordRecoveryController(_mockRepo.Object);

    var httpContext = new Moq.Mock<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext>();
    httpContext.Setup( x => x.Request.Form).Returns(GetFormCollection());  

    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext.Object;          

    var result = await controller.Save();
    var viewResult = Xunit.Assert.IsType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult>(result);
    Xunit.Assert.Equal("~/Views/PasswordRecovery.cshtml", viewResult.ViewName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Moq, you can do it like this:

```
var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();           

httpContext.Setup(c => c.Request.Form).Returns(delegate()
{
    var formVaues = new NameValueCollection();
    formVaues .Add("Id", "123");
    formVaues .Add("Name", "Smith");

    return formVaues ;
});
```

Comment: In ASP.NET Core it should be ```HttpContext```, not ```HttpContextBase```.

Answer (score 4):

If you pass a `DefaultHttpContext` to your controller, `Request` won't be null and you can assign the form to `Request.Form`. No mocking required.

```
[Xunit.Fact]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SavePassNotEqualTest()
{
    var controller = new Controllers.PasswordRecoveryController(_mockRepo.Object);
    var dic = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>();
    dic.Add("password", "test");
    dic.Add("password1", "test1");
    var collection = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormCollection(dic);

    // Give the controller an HttpContext.
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    // Request is not null anymore.
    controller.Request.Form = collection;  

    var result = await controller.Save();
    var viewResult = Xunit.Assert.IsType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult>(result);
    Xunit.Assert.Equal("~/Views/Message.cshtml", viewResult.ViewName);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Moq you can try to use Setup() or SetupGet() to teach it to return something that you need

something along the lines of

```
controller.SetupGet(x => x.Request.Form).Returns(collection);
```